# How to start a cloned xen virtual machine

Tags: xen, boot, startup, clone

I cloned a machine using:

```
virt-clone --prompt
```

Now it's sitting in my `/vm` folder. How do I power it on (from the console)?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.

```
xm create /etc/xen/domainname
```

where "/etc/xen/domainname" is the config file with the name given to the instance.